# Condition for neutral equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

Do rate of change of force with respect to $x$ $\frac{dF}{dx} = 0$ at the equilibrium position imply that it is the neutral equilibrium position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For instance, the force $F=-kx^3$ has $\frac{dF}{dx}|_{x=0}=0$, but is nevertheless a stable equilibrium.

Neutral equilibrium requires $\frac{dF}{dx}=0$, but $\frac{dF}{dx}=0$ does not imply neutral equilibrium. Higher-order derivatives need to be examined.

Comment: Damn, beaten to it! :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm impressed that you almost beat me to it, *and* yours has a graph ;)

Comment: @Chris Thanks you, confusion got clear. I checked out many books but didn't get this!!

Answer (score 0):

$dF/dx=0$ implies that the position is locally neutral. You'd need to look at the higher order derivatives to see if it was globally neutral. For example consider this force distance curve:

[image]

This has $F=0$ and $F'=0$ at $x=0$, but it is obviously only locally neutral.